# Manga (or Anime) where the protagonist is put in charge of a barren plot and grows a rare plant

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

I either watched this a while back or read it but in the show/manga the main character is put in charge of barren land that's doesn't have much value. If I recall correctly it was as a reward for something but a group of people wanted to not really give him anything so they give him what essentially was badlands.  He then grows the rare plant in it, I think it was flowers, by controlling the weather with magic and uses that money to turn the area into a thriving area/cityscape. Setting was pretty basic as like all fantasy/isekais usually are. (no idea if it was an isekai or not)

If it was a anime if was definitely subbed and it seemed to be a recent one as the graphics in it were pretty good. It was probably watched on gogoanime. It was also probably a series rather than an OVA or movie style length.

If manga it was Japanese manga and not Chinese or Korean.
It's been bugging me for awhile now and I can't recall the title or find it. If anyone knows that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did I add enough Val or should I go and just keep searching on my own?

Comment: I can't speak for Valorum, but personally, I think that should be enough information. Welcome to the site! Hopefully we can track this down for you.

Comment: @Hideo - That's plenty of info, but if there's [anything else you think of](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) you should add that in as well

Comment: Do you remember how many chapters you read or episodes you watched? More specifically, when in the story did the MC get this reward? Was it at the very start for something that happened before the start of the story, or was it a reward for events in the story?

Comment: Hmm... I remember we had one like this recently, with a younger son of a noble being sent to a remote location (an island?) that was considered of little worth, and him succeeding due to his growing prowess.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254940 ? I haven't read it but that seems to be mining-focused, not plants. Might be a good start for similar stories.

Comment: is it colored or not? This sound like middle plot of a manhwa I know

Comment: Yeah it is. It never really mentioned or had anything that would allude to it being Korean as I've seen some Manga that have had color in them. The only thing I saw was one line in a chapter towards the very end after I had rediscovered it, where the younger brother shouted the Korean word for brother. So that's my bad. Any way the series is titled The Max Level Hero has Returned! or the Max Level Hero Strikes Back.

Comment: @Hideo You should be able to post that as an answer yourself, so you can mark it as accepted. That will also help anyone else who comes along in the future looking for the same manhwa.

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed in the comments, this was *[The Max Level Hero Strikes Back](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-max-level-hero-strikes-back)*

> Struck by an enemy’s arrow, the powerless Prince Davey O’Rowane falls into a coma. His soul travels to a place where the greatest of the great gather—the honorable Hall of Heroes. There a thousand years pass as Davey undergoes excruciating training under their watchful eyes to become a hero too strong for his own good. Now back to his timeline and his kingdom, he’s wide awake and the enemies hiding in the king’s court better be prepared. The prince they had dismissed is now their biggest threat!

It seems the manhua has a webtoon version on [Tapas](https://m.tapas.io/series/the-max-level-hero-strikes-back/info).