# Webnovel where the prince has a tiny demon girl only he can see following him; he gets sent to the worst region of the country

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I remember reading this manhwa a while ago but I can't seem to find it again.

The story goes with the prince being a reincarnated hero or something with a small fairy like demon girl following him. He is very overpowered but he gets sent to the worst region of the country to keep him out of the power struggle.

He develops it nicely and starts farming some kinda flower which is used to make potions and the whole region's climate is controlled through some ancient crystal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "a while ago?"  Do you remember what site you read it on?  Was it translated?

Comment: Hi David, thanks. I read it about 2 months ago (October 2021) and it was translated to English. It was on a third party site, i don't remember exactly which.

Comment: Possibly The Max Level Hero has Returned? I've never read it so I can't confirm, but it sounds similar to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256956

Comment: OMG! Yes that's the one thanks a lot, now I have some peace of mind and can finally catch up. The Max Level Hero has Returned! The main narrative of the plot was what i was missing which is that 
>! the MC was trained by all the previous generation of heroes in the hall of heroes after falling into a coma due to a failed assassination attempt
also am i doing something wrong with the spoiler marking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, this is [The Max Level Hero Strikes Back](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-max-level-hero-strikes-back)

> Struck by an enemy’s arrow, the powerless Prince Davey O’Rowane falls into a coma. His soul travels to a place where the greatest of the great gather—the honorable Hall of Heroes. There a thousand years pass as Davey undergoes excruciating training under their watchful eyes to become a hero too strong for his own good.

The reincarnation aspect is his training in the hall of heroes while in a coma. He is eventually sent off to another region to get rid of him, along with a small demon girl:

[image]

and uses the power of a crystal to help change the weather. I believe this crystal (and other smaller ones) is just a power source, not a specific weather-crystal or anything.

[image]